# Is there a way to distinguish between a function argument's default value having been passed explicitly or implicitly in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, default-parameters

Assuming a kotlin function like this:

```kotlin
fun f(p1: T1? = null, p2: T2? = null, ..., pN: TN? = null) {
    // ...
}
```

Can the above function's implementation distinguish between the following two calls, where the first one passed `p1 = null` implicitly, and the second one passed it explicitly?

```kotlin
f()          // Implicit
f(null)      // Explicit
f(p1 = null) // Explicit
```

Note: There could be arbitrary numbers of parameters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it cannot distinguish between those cases.

You could distinguish between them if you added a distinct overload, however.

Comment: In the real world case, I have N parameters, so overloading won't work...

Answer (score 1):

Although I'd rather not use that approach in production, you could do something like I've done in the following snippet:

```kotlin
object Default {
    val defaultMapping = mutableMapOf<KClass<*>, Any?>()

    inline fun <reified T> get(): T? =
            T::class.let {
                defaultMapping[it] ?: it.java.constructors.getOrNull(0)?.let { c ->
                    try {
                        // NOTE: for now only parameterles constructor will work
                        c.newInstance()
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                        null
                    }.also { v ->
                        defaultMapping[it] = v
                    }
                } ?: run {
                    defaultMapping[it] = null
                    null
                }
            } as? T

    inline fun <reified T> T.isDefault(): Boolean = defaultMapping[T::class] == this
}

inline fun <reified T> foo(bar: T? = Default.get()) {
    if (bar?.isDefault() == true) println("bar: default is in use")
    else println("bar: $bar")
}

fun main() {
    foo<Any>()
    foo(Default.get<Any>())
    foo<Any>(null)
    foo<Any>(bar = null)
    foo(Any())
    val a = Any()
    foo(a)
    foo(bar = a)
}
```

Note, that I have not polished the code in any way. Some parts are leftovers from several attempts (e.g. the part about the `constructors.getOrNull(0)`) and I don't intend to improve that.

Also: This simple approach only works with default constructors (see `it.newInstance()`) on the JVM. So that's no multi-platform solution in any way.

The result is something like

```
bar: default is in use
bar: default is in use
bar: null
bar: null
bar: java.lang.Object@41906a77
bar: java.lang.Object@4b9af9a9
bar: java.lang.Object@4b9af9a9
```

**Again: Keep in mind, this is very simplistic, don't use that in production!**